# SQL join into array for each table

Tags: php, sql, join

I am joining two tables: `customers` and `queries`.

I am getting the `full_name` from the `customers` table and the `description` from the `queries` table.

I am wondering if it is possible to have the results of an SQL join split into arrays that correspond with the table the data came from? For example:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT queries.description, customers.full_name FROM queries INNER JOIN customers ON queries.customer_id = customers.id");
$STH->execute();

$queries = $STH->fetchAll();
```

At the moment, I can access my data like this: `$queries[0]['description']` and `$queries[0]['full_name']`

However, my question is whether there is an easy way to get the data like so: `$job[0]['query']['description']` and `$job[0]['customer']['full_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as teresko mentioned, I can't understand why you'd need that.

I can only imagine you want to see on the PHP code what are the table that contained the information.

Maybe you could do something like SELECT queries.description as queries_description, then your php code would look like `$queries['queries_description']`. Would it be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the results in PHP and convert it to the data structure you want, but you cannot (as far as I know) automatically group the data into arrays based on the source table. A (somewhat messy) alternative, using SQL is to use a multi-query and create a temp table from your original results, then select the results on a per-table basis, like so:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE q AS 
   (SELECT queries.description, customers.full_name FROM queries 
        INNER JOIN customers 
        ON queries.customer_id = customers.id
    );
SELECT q.description FROM q;
SELECT q.full_name FROM q;
```

So, in those `SELECT` statements, you'll have to list all the columns that you want for each result. Then in PHP, you'll have to iterate over each resultset and put the data into arrays (or objects/whatever) as needed. Errr. A fetchAll will still not get you what you want, but a fetchAll on the first non-empty resultset will get you all the rows from `queries` and the 2nd will get you all the rows from `customers`